# How to save custom option field value when create order programmatically?

Tags: orders, custom-options

I have been trying to create order programatically, it's working well except custom option.

I have one custom option which reference id is **435.** I have tried the following. But it seems not working

```
$order->setData(array( 'options' => array(
     435 => $customvalue,
)));
```

I got above suggestion From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290514/magento-programmatically-create-order-with-custom-option-of-type-date#answer-21303058)

How to save custom option field value when create order programatically?

Comment: I've never been able to do so, as the order custom values seem to be lost from one step to the other, the way I worked around this was by using session variables. I'd be interested to see the answer to this too.

Comment: @JulienLachal i have posted answer! you can check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer for my question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687630/howto-update-order-items-custom-option-in-magento)

Its working rock

```
$existentOptions['additional_options'][] = array(
'label' => $optiontitle, // Title of custom option field
'value' => $customvalue,  // Value of custom option field
);
```

For more details, you can check on [my blog here](http://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/to-save-custom-options-when-create-order-programmatically/)

Comment: I should test that someday. And is it kept throughout the whole Checkout process?

Comment: yeah. I got these custom values in sales/order module in backend too

Comment: I guess you must have added another field to the sales_order table then?